# Regex for only some chars

Tags: c#, regex

I have this text:

```
33113 1;3;\"windlight \"\"Feeling\"\"\r\nmetal, handmade\r\ninside: gold
metallic\r\noutisde: anthracite brushed\r\nH. 14 cm - B. 11,5 
cm\";7,95;4001250331131;218,625;262,35;579;21;0004;0001;KUS\r\n
```

And this regex:

```
;\\"[^;]*\\";
```

Which gives the result:

```
;\"windlight \"\"Feeling\"\"\r\nmetal, handmade\r\ninside: gold metallic\r\noutisde: anthracite brushed\r\nH. 14 cm - B. 11,5 cm\";
```

Where I like to remove the new-line characters `\r\n`.Have you any ideas please?

I need something like this:

```
var replaced = Regex.Replace( 
                "a regex pattern which removes \r\n from the selected text", " ");
```

This is what I want to remove from text:
http://postimg.org/image/5hbtd1czx/

Comment: What exactly you want? You want all `\r\n` characters from the text, you want to remove them, something else?

Comment: I want to remove \r\n from my result....But I have a lot of this rows and i want to select only \r\n in my result and after that i replace it for space

Comment: Simple `string.Replace("\r\n", "")` doesn't serve your purpose?

Comment: Regex.Replace() supports 3 arguments?

Comment: I havent "myString"...i want to remove \r\n from only some parts of text....I have about 1000rows and in this rows i want to remove \r\n, but only in the parts which i select with my regex....i want to edit my regex to select only \r\n in the part which i now select with my regex :)

Comment: this is i want to remove: <http://postimg.org/image/5hbtd1czx/>

Comment: so your issue was solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use replace:

```
myString = text.Replace("\r\n", "")
```

**EDIT:**

```
myString = text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ")
```

or

```
myString = text.Replace("\r\n", " ").Replace("\r", " ").Replace("\n", " ");
```

Also note that

```
string[] myString = File.ReadAllLines(yourTextFile);
```

This will automatically remove all the \n and \r from your text.

Comment: I havent "myString"...i want to remove \r\n from only some parts of text....I have about 1000rows and in this rows i want to remove \r\n, but only in the parts which i select with my regex....i want to edit my regex to select only \r\n in the part which i now select with my regex :)

Comment: i dont want to remove \r\n from all text...i want to remove only from parts of text..

Comment: I determining  the parts of text with my regex:  ;\\"[^;]*\\";     But i need to update my regex to select only \r\n from this parts of text :)

Comment: @Jane:- Its confusing now. You want to change your regex or you want to replace \r\n from the string which your regex has returned? BTW what is your regex doing?

Comment: Sorry...i have a lot of text rows and in the name of item i have a lot of \r\n and this i want t oreplace to space. But only in the name of item: ;\"windlight \"\"Feeling\"\"\r\nmetal, handmade\r\ninside: gold metallic\r\noutisde: anthracite brushed\r\nH. 14 cm - B. 11,5 cm\";     and others...

Answer (score 0):

So for example,

```
 String str = "Text contains \r \n string here";
 str = str.Replace("(\r\n", " "); // with blank space
```

Comment: In `C#`, it's `Replace()`.

Comment: Sorry, you not understood me...i want this: var replaced = Regex.Replace(myalltext, "my regex which save only \r\n in the text which i now in regex", "space");

Comment: yeah actually I have copied from test application, so I forgot to remove it. sorry for that.

Comment: to get the result we can copy the text in string.

Comment: I havent "myString"...i want to remove \r\n from only some parts of text....I have about 1000rows and in this rows i want to remove \r\n, but only in the parts which i select with my regex....i want to edit my regex to select only \r\n in the part which i now select with my regex :)

Comment: "saving \r\n" and "removing \r\n" are contrary statements, I edited your question to clearify it